# Where to obtain Google Website Optimizer Tool for A/B Testing?

Tags: testing, ab-testing

I have tried many times but didn't get any proper source to download and install Google Website Optimizer Tool for A/B Testing. Please tell me where can I get this tool. I never used any tool for testing before it.

Answer (score 0):

This project has been retired
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Website_Optimizer

It has been integrated into Google analytics though.